# How to programmatically download a file from a remote desktop if I have the data required to configure a Jump Desktop (remote desktop) connection?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, remote-desktop, rdp, vnc

I want to programmatically download a file from a remote machine.

So, I know the host's IP and port:

[image]

Login data:
[image]

I also know that it creates an SSH tunnel.

Any suggestions? Is it even possible knowing just that data?

My knowledge on that topic is very scarce.

Answer (score 0):

My answer focuses on SSH usage. In order to download a file via SSH, you need to run the scp command, like

```
scp yourusername@server.url:/the/path/to/the/file.extension ./
```

That's enough in order to download the file. However, it is possible that this will not work by itself. First, you need the other machine to know about your ssh, so you will need to

```
vim ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

hit insert and paste your public SSH key to its end. Don't remove anything. If it is still not working, then ssh might be disallowed on the server and you will need to enable it. Example for Ubuntu: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-ssh-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Your user needs access to the file you want to download, otherwise this won't work.

Alternatively you could set up an SFTP connection as well and use that.